# Using string in java array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, jagged-arrays

I need to put several strings into a java array for example.

```
"Dog","Cat","Lion","Giraffe"
"Car","Truck","Boat","RV"
```

each of the above would be 1 key in the array

```
array[0] = "Dog","Cat","Lion","Giraffe"
array[1] =  "Car","Truck","Boat","RV"
```

Not sure how to do this,or should I be using something other than an array,and how to get each individual element i.e `array[0]"Lion"`

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare the array like this:

```
String [][]array = { 
    { "Dog","Cat","Lion","Giraffe"}, 
    {"Car","Truck","Boat","RV"}
};
```

and use the items like this:

```
array[0][0]; // this would be "Dog"
array[1][0]; // this would be "Car"
```

Comment: he wanted multiple items per key, not the individual ones

Answer (score 1):

You can use a multidimensional array:

```
String[][] something =
    { 
        { "hello", "kitties" }, 
        {  "i", "am", "a", "pony" } 
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do it by declaring a map like so `Map<String, MySweetObject>` or create a `List<String>` and put each list into the array.

Answer (score 0):

You need a jagged array, which is an array of arrays:

```
String [][]array  = { {"Dog","Cat","Lion","Giraffe"}, {"Car","Truck","Boat","RV"}};
```

You can then access the content as this:

```
array[0] // will be the String array {"Dog","Cat","Lion","Giraffe"}
array[1] // will be the String array {"Car","Truck","Boat","RV"}
array[0][2] // Lion
array[1][0] // Car
```